# Sqlldr tab delim file load issue

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm trying to load a tab delim file into a table.
Pls check the issue below and help.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'tab1.txt'
BADFILE 'tab1.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'tab1.dsc'
REPLACE INTO TABLE CL_TAB1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'9' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
A,B,C,D,E
)
```

tab1.txt File is like below

```
A   B   C   D   E
799 CP  AM  27-12-2017
800 CP      18-05-2017
801             USA
```

1. If i don't mention TRAILING NULLCOLS with column names, sqlldr loads only null values into table.
2. When I listed col names in TRAILING NULLCOLS, sqlldr loads like below in the table.

---

```
A   B   C   D   E
799 CP  AM  27-12-2017      (Note: this is ok record)
800 CP  18-05-2017          (Note: 18-05-2017 should be loaded onto D col, but loaded onto C)
801 USA                     (Note: USA should be loaded onto E col, but loaded onto B)
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mention `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` --> `SQLLDR` is working correctly.

See my example:

**DDL**

```
DROP TABLE TAB1;

CREATE TABLE TAB1 (
    A   VARCHAR2(100),
    B   VARCHAR2(100),
    C   VARCHAR2(100),
    D   VARCHAR2(100),
    E   VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

**Tab1.txt**

```
A   B   C   D   E
799 CP  AM  27-12-2017
800 CP      18-05-2017
801             USA
```

**Control file**

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'tab1.txt'
BADFILE 'tab1.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'tab1.dsc'
REPLACE INTO TABLE TAB1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'9'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
A,B,C,D,E
)
```

**SQLLDR execution**

```
>sqlldr userid=tejash/***** control=tab1.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Jul 2 11:43:33 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 3
Commit point reached - logical record count 4

Table TAB1:
  4 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  tab1.log
for more information about the load.
```

**Data in table TAB1**

```
A   B   C   D   E
799 CP  AM  27-12-2017  
800 CP      18-05-2017  
801             USA
```

[image]

The first row of a text file is just a header and If you want to skip the header then you will need to use `OPTIONS(skip=1)` in control file.

Comment: You said "If you don't mention TRAILING NULLCOLS with column names --> SQLLDR is working correctly." but probably meant to say **OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'**.

Comment: Ohh my bad!! Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you, it works great..

I have one more issue...pls help.

In few records, i have one of the fields in the file, say C with data like below - within quotes, values and a comma and then tab and values example: "XXXX, YYY-YYY"

Due to this, table is loaded as below C D XXXX YYY-YYY

Comment: I think this is the limitation, I don't have any idea. Sorry!!. You can write another question so that other experts can help. You can give reference to this question in the new question.